# Convert BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB to CV_8UC3 with JavaCV

Tags: python, java, c++, opencv, javacv

I've been working on something similiar to OpenTrack in Java. I have working example with Demo Video opened with FFMpegGrabber but now I'm trying to implement it with PS3 Eye Webcam. I'm using JavaCV and I've tried to get CL-Eye SDK but now it is impossible to register at their site what is needed to get DLL Library for my PS3 Eye webcam. I've found https://github.com/diwi/PS3Eye based on libusb.

My code looks like this:

```
public Frame grab() {
    int frame_w = ps3eye.getResolution().w;
    int frame_h = ps3eye.getResolution().h;
    BufferedImage frame = new BufferedImage(frame_w, frame_h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) frame.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    ps3eye.getFrame(pixels);
    framerate.update();

    Mat image = new Mat(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), CV_32SC4);
    image.put(0, 0, pixels);
    List<Mat> channels = new ArrayList<>(4);
    Core.split(image, channels);
    Collections.swap(channels,0,channels.size()-1);
    Core.merge(channels, image);

    Mat finalImage = new Mat(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), CV_8UC3);
    cvtColor(image, finalImage, COLOR_RGBA2BGR);

    return CONVERTER.convert(finalImage);
}
```

My further operations base on SimpleBlobDetectour, findContours and cvtColors which are working fine with video file and CV_8UC3 type - but 32S is not supported especially by cvtColors and I need 3 image channels for FrameConverter. Do you have any idea how to do it properly? Thanks!

Comment: AFAICT `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` means each pixel is packed into the 4 bytes of a 32bit integer, so `CV_32SC4` definitely seems wrong -- only 1/4 of the `Mat` will be populated, and with nonsense values at that. You ought to be able to check that in a debugger.

Comment: I don't do Java, but I assume `pixels` is just a view of the underlying `frame` buffer. So you should also be able to do a similar cast via `DataBufferByte` to get an array of bytes... and store that in a `CV_8UC4` `Mat`.

Comment: @DanMašek I've tried different types and Mat put() method throws an error of incompatible data types. I've searched through forum and in every thread regarding BufferedImage and OpenCV TYPE_INT_ARGB and TYPE_INT_RGB are packed into CV_32S. And that's true,  integer with the sign data type in OpenCV corresponds to CV_32S.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solutions was seriously easier than I've expected (even though I thought I've tried this method).

```
public Frame grab() {
    int frame_w = ps3eye.getResolution().w;
    int frame_h = ps3eye.getResolution().h;
    BufferedImage frame = new BufferedImage(frame_w, frame_h, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) frame.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    ps3eye.getFrame(pixels);
    framerate.update();
    Mat finalImage = new Mat(frame_h, frame_w, CV_8UC3);
    finalImage.put(0, 0, pixels);

    return CONVERTER.convert(finalImage);
}
```

I haven't though that changing BufferedImage type will automatically get proper data and the order of bytes.

[IR-Head-Tracker test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvOZ3.png)